# External display changing brightness based on what's shown

Tags: windows, laptop, external-display, brightness

I'm using a Dell Inspiron laptop running Windows 7, with a Samsung SyncMaster P2250 connected via D-SUB as external display. The display seems to dynamically adjust it's brightness based on what's shown and I have found this to be quite frustrating: Darker scenes in movies get even darker, making it hard to distinguish anything. The display works fine if there are a lot of lit areas in what's currently shown.

How do I disable this feature? I've tried setting the brightness on the display, but it won't let me (brightness is gray, can't adjust it). The built-in screen of the laptop does not suffer from this issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Monitor menu -> Picture -> MagicBright

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for a feature named Magic Bright

In the monitor's menu, go to Picture then Magic Bright. Choose the value that you like best (most probably you were in the Dynamic mode therefore the automatic brightness adjustments)